# Почему метод Date.now() показывает разное время, будучи инициализированным вне функции или внутри

Tags: javascript, функции, дата

Почему метод Date.now(), если переменная объявлена внутри функции, показывает время примерно на 5 милисекунд позже, чем вне? Связано ли это с тем, что это задержка вызова функции после загрузки?

```
var nowOuter = Date.now(); 
var nowInner;

function draw() {
  nowInner = Date.now();
  alert("Внеш. время: " + nowOuter + " Внут. время: " + nowInner);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  draw();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Nata_Hamster/7jkdx5w4/

Comment: У меня разница две МИЛЛИСЕКУНДЫ. Метод возвращает значение в миллисекундах.

Comment: @Leonid да, перепутала. 5 МИЛИсекунд. Каждый раз по разному. Было и по 6, и по 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, вызов `draw()` будет осуществлен после построения дерева DOM, к тому времени значение переменной `nowOuter` уже задано и остается неизменным. Легко проверить изменив код:

```js
var nowOuter = Date.now(); 
var nowInner;

function draw() {
  nowInner = Date.now();
  console.log("Внеш. время: " + nowOuter + " Внут. время: " + nowInner);
}

document.getElementById('click').addEventListener('click', function() {
  draw();
});
```

```html
<button id='click'>Click</button>
```

А так можно узнать время на построение этого дерева (в миллисекундах с точностью до микросекунды):

```js
let now = performance.now();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log(performance.now() - now);
});
```